# Multisite for main in subdirectory, subdomain and subfolders (EN/ES)

Tags: multisite, directory, subdomains

I have a domain `<http://my-site.com>` and I want to restructure it, used to have a Drupal for the portal and numerous installations of WordPress in different subdomains. The hosting I have only allows me to access cpanel (limited) and ftp.

What I want to do is a single installation of WordPress multisite for the main domain, subdomains and subsites, ie:

```
<http://my-site.com>  
<http://blog1.my-site.com>  
<http://blog2.my-site.com>  
<http://blog2.my-site.com/blog3> or <http://blog3.blog2.my-site.com>
<http://blog2.my-site.com/blog4> or <http://blog4.blog2.my-site.com>
```

All these sites should be independent of each other (although they share the themes and plugins) What would be the easiest way to do this?
From what I've been looking on the internet, I found how to make the subdomains, but to make the installation of multisites only gives me the option of subfolders, which does not help.

On the other hand, is it possible to do this without installing Wordpress on my root? It's simply for organizing files. That is:

```
<http://my-site.com> <- Access URL  
</www/site/>         <- installation directory (/www is the root)
```

As it had before, in the root I had a `/www/index.html` what redirected to `/www/site/index.php`. Being this last the Drupal directory. This system doesn't help as it enters an infinite loop of redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that what you want is possible.

Per the [WordPress Codex page on Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network):

> You are given the choice between sub-domains and sub-directories,
>   except when existing settings restrict your choice.
>
> You must choose one or the other.

So you can set your network up to use either sub-domains OR sub-directories for your child sites, but not both.

So you could do either:

```
<http://my-site.com>
<http://blog1.my-site.com>
<http://blog2.my-site.com>
<http://blog3.my-site.com>
<http://blog4.my-site.com>
```

OR:

```
<http://my-site.com>
<http://my-site.com/blog1>
<http://my-site.com/blog2>
<http://my-site.com/blog3>
<http://my-site.com/blog4>
```

But you cannot combine the two (E.g. this `<http://blog2.my-site.com/blog3>` is not possible, so far as I know).

As for installing WordPress Multisite in its own directory, [this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) should give you all the info you need. If you have specific questions about any of the information in it, please ask them.

Finally, this page might also be of interest: [Do you really need a network?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#WordPress_Settings_Requirements)

Comment: Thanks @Burgon
The same is the conclusion I have drawn from what I've been reading and trying. Another possibility may be to use `.htaccess`, no? Will investigate this possibility.  
About what move the root to another directory, the link has served me perfect.

Comment: Sure, you could potentially use .htaccess to redirect visitors, but it sounds like a nightmare to try and use it to make WordPress act in a way its not designed to act. It would be much easier to create a new site architecture and redirect all of your old links that moved as a result of the change (at least, that's how I think).